# What does django PayPal IPN look like?

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have implemented django PayPal IPN and have some difficulties with the received ipn. Can anyone give information about it? What are the functions it supports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, IPN processing will handle the followings,

- receive/verify the PayPal POST-backs
- Parse the verfied POST-back message and update your database with the transaction details from it

This is what a typical IPN message looks like, your Django script will be working to deal these HTTP posts from PayPal, and process order management operations (e.g. update DB) based on them

> transaction_subject=&payment_date=20%3A08%3A00+Sep+01%2C+2015+PDT&last_name=US&residence_country=US&item_name=Test+Description%3A+Batch+Register&payment_gross=-10.00&mc_currency=USD&payment_type=instant&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&verify_sign=AmDuhskOW4nHRQzwOcT1kVh.Nd7aA8jucGH77Q.R4aiejb1M3rSyseJs&test_ipn=1&payer_email=USP%40email.com&txn_id=77R67849J7462684N&receiver_email=hanban%40paypal.com&first_name=Payer&parent_txn_id=5GY14152509151407&invoice=INV-KZXY-BATCH002&payer_id=8FMFQ2KVYYHTY&receiver_id=XPKMZXNEA2GXU&reason_code=refund&item_number=&handling_amount=0.00&payment_status=Refunded&payment_fee=-0.39&mc_fee=-0.39&shipping=0.00&mc_gross=-10.00&custom=Test+Custom%3A+KZXY&charset=UTF-8&notify_version=3.8&ipn_track_id=58d1b52cca4ad

As Django or PayPal recommended, it would be always ease to test your functions with the Sandbox environment and PayPal IPN simulator, you might have already walked through [the Django IPN docs](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html#testing), just in case you need anything in detail, you will get everything in there.